# drag and drop elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Maybe can you help me, i would like to create one column with dragable (not clone) divs, which i can put into the container, which consists of four divs (bootstrap col-md-3). Dragable elements have two sizes: col-md-3 or col-md-6. I found something similar (http://jsfiddle.net/py3DE/) but i cant rewrite it to work properly

```
    $(".source .item").draggable({ revert: "invalid", appendTo: 'body', helper: 'clone',
    start: function(ev, ui){ ui.helper.width($(this).width()); }                    // ensure helper width
});

$(".target .empty").droppable({ tolerance: 'pointer', hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui){
        var item = ui.draggable;
        if (!ui.draggable.closest('.empty').length) item = item.clone().draggable();// if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
        this.innerHTML = '';                                                        // clean the placeholder
        item.css({ top: 0, left: 0 }).appendTo(this);                                // append item to placeholder
    }
});

$(".target").on('click', '.closer', function(){
    var item = $(this).closest('.item');
    item.fadeTo(200, 0, function(){ item.remove(); })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you update 'item.clone().draggable()' to 'item.draggable()', it won't clone.

[js code](http://jsfiddle.net/py3DE/203/)

```
  if (!ui.draggable.closest('.empty').length) item = item.draggable()
```

Comment: great, but how can i sovle bootstrap problem with element's width?